# if arbitrary intersection of compact sets is empty, then there exists at least two sets that are disjoint?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, compactness

if arbitrary intersection of compact set is empty, then there exists at least two sets that are disjoint?

Generally, I know the argument is false as nested intersection of open sets are empty, but there is not pair-wise disjoint. How about compact sets (closed and bounded in real line?)

Comment: Cover a circle with three arcs …

Comment: Let $A = [2,5]$, $B = [4,7]$ and $C = [0,3]\cup[6,9]$.

Comment: Use pairs. $ $ $ $

Answer (score 0):

As you already know from comments, in general the claim is false, but it holds for *convex* compact subsets of the real line as one-dimensional case of [Helly’s theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helly%27s_theorem).